# unable to start ballerina as gateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, ballerina

I've downloaded the WSO2-ApiManager-3.0.0-m2 release and I'm trying to invoke an api via the ballerina gateway(version 0.88). When I'm trying to start ballerina with:

`bin/ballerina run service deployment/org/wso2/apim/`

it gives me `ballerina: no such file or directory: deployment/org/wso2/apim`

If I manually create that directory in $gwHome I get `ballerina: no bal files in the package: deployment/org/wso2/apim`

How do I start the ballerina gateway?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2-ApiManager-3.0.0-m2 works with ballerina 0.85 version. Here you have to set an environment variable as 'gwHome' by pointing to the Ballerina home directory. Then start APIM and publish an API which will create the deployment/org/wso2/apim path in ballerina and also create an API there. 
Then you can start ballerina with the same command.

Also note that, APIM 3.0.0 M3 will be released end of this week or early next week, which has major changes.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issues with the 0.85 version. Seems like no API is created in the deployment/org/wso2/apim folder. I get "ballerina: no bal files in the package:" Is the environment variable suppose to be set via export gwHome=/path/to/ballerina" or supplied as an argument on startup via "-Denvironment=/path/to/ballerina" ?