# WSO2 apim 3.0.0 M6, unable to start the gateway

Tags: wso2

For 3.0.0-M6, installing as per
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM300/Installation+Guide
and then publishing the pet store api described at:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM300/Create+and+Publish+an+API

Then, when trying to start the gateway, this message is received:

> ballerina: no bal files in the package: org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway

I've seen a an older post at

> [unable to start ballerina as gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550713/unable-to-start-ballerina-as-gateway)

where some developer suggested adding an environment variable to have the publisher copy data directly into the file structure of the gateway, but it doesn't describe how to set the environment variable.

Is this still a viable solution? Is there any point in installing and running the five processes locally and expect deployment of apis to work locally? It seems to me the milestone is still a few milestones away from proper testing on localhost.

The docs on this are still a bit sparse...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has been updated now on how to start the gateway [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM300/Installation+Guide